# OpenCMS 8.0/9.0/9.5.2 upload error in all browsers

Tags: opencms

I have tried **OpenCMS** 8 to 9 versions in **Glassfish** server. The installation was successful. But when I try to upload any files or images using opencms workplace Upload button, It throws **`"No File items found in the request"`**. Please see the attached image

[image]

Comment: I have tried GWT Upload, Basic Upload and Applet too. none of them seems to be working. All throws the same error

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Comment: I stopped using opencms... Switched to wordpress